# В чем причина низкой производительности дроплета в DigitalOcean?

Tags: java, tomcat, digitalocean

Доброе время суток! Создал дроплет в Digital Ocean с 1GB оперативной памяти, 20GB объемом жесткого диска и 2TB траффика. ОС - Debian 8.9 x32. Дроплет во Франкфурте. Поднял томкат на этом дроплете. Проблема заключается в низкой скорости загрузки даже главной страницы томката. Вот скрипт службы томката (tomcat.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat9
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/tomcat9.pid
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dnet.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck=t$
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

В чем может быть проблема с производительностью томката и дроплета?